# How to retrieve data from SQL database in vb. net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem in retrieving data from database.. I have 3 textboxes and textbox1 is for applicant_num,  textbox2 is for applicant_name and textbox3 is for Lot_num and i want to view those data in listview..  how can I get the data from database using vb.net? Hope you can help me.. thanks.

Code is here:

```
dim sql as string = "select * from Pambujan where app_num = '" & textbox1. text & "',  app_name = '" & textbox2. text & "',  lot_num = '" & textbox3. text &"'"
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for accessing the Text property of the text boxes is incorrect. Also, the dynamic WHERE clause being generated should use 'AND' instead of commas. Something like this:

```
dim sql as string = "SELECT * from Pambujan WHERE app_num = '" & textbox1.Text & "' AND app_name = '" & textbox2.Text & "' AND lot_num = '" & textbox3.Text &"';"
```

Comment: ***AND*** you should **always** use **parametrized queries** to avoid SQL injection, too! **ALWAYS**